# Algorithm for scaling two values (positive or negative) to between 0 and 1

Tags: swift

I'm looking for an algorithm that will scale and consolidate two numbers:

```swift
func scale(x: Int, y: Int) -> Double { 
    // algorithm here
    return 0.5
}
```

The algorithm must satisfy the following constraints:

- Return values between `0` and `1`
- If `x` and `y` are the same return `0.5`
- If `x` is "bigger"* than `y` return some number `> 0.5`
- If `y` is "bigger"* than `x` return some number `< 0.5`
- Return values are relative, so `scale(x: -5, y: 4) < scale(x: -5, y: 0) == True`
- * -1 is "bigger" than -2

Here's the test suite (for use in a Swift Playground):

```swift
import Foundation
import XCTest

func XCTAssertBetween(_ value: Double, _ range: ClosedRange<Double>, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "", file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
    XCTAssertGreaterThanOrEqual(value, range.lowerBound, "Value is less than lower bound", file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertLessThanOrEqual(value, range.upperBound, "Value is more than upper bound", file: file, line: line)
}

class ScaleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testZZ() {
        XCTAssertEqual(scale(x: 0, y: 0), 0.5)
    }
    
    func testPP() {
        XCTAssertEqual(scale(x: 1, y: 1), 0.5)
    }
    
    func testPZ() {
        XCTAssertBetween(scale(x: 1, y: 0), 0.51...1)
    }
    
    func testZP() {
        XCTAssertBetween(scale(x: 0, y: 1), 0...0.49)
    }
    
    func testNN() {
        XCTAssertEqual(scale(x: -1, y: -1), 0.5)
    }
    
    func testZN() {
        XCTAssertBetween(scale(x: 0, y: -1), 0.51...1)
    }
    
    func testNZ() {
        XCTAssertBetween(scale(x: -1, y: 0), 0...0.49)
    }
}
  
ScaleTests.defaultTestSuite.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), and any properly scaled sigmoid will do this. Starting with your difference:

```
let d = Double(x) - Double(y)
```

Some example scaled Sigmoids:

```
return 1 / (1 + exp(-d)) // Logistic function as emehex demonstrated

return atan(d) / .pi + 0.5

return tanh(d) / 2 + 0.5 // Another form of the logistic

return 0.5 + d / (2*sqrt(1 + d * d))
```

The [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) is the traditional one to use in this case, but you may want others for performance or other characteristics.

As @emehex notes, the logistic function may bunch up the values more than you like within your scale. You can fix that by rescaling `d`, multiplying or dividing it by whatever you like to get the "steepness" you want.

Depending on how much you're using this, you may want to look at one of the [several sigmoid functions](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=sigmoid&type=Documentation) available in the Apple ecosystem. This function is extremely common in machine learning applications.

Comment: I think the `return atan(d) / .pi + 0.5` will do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is close (it satisfies all of the tests):

```swift
func scale(x: Int, y: Int) -> Double {
    let val = Double(x - y)
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-val))
}
```

But I don't love that all of these are ~= 0.99:

```swift
scale(x: 5, y: 0) // wish this was 0.8-ish
scale(x: 10, y: 0) // 0.90-ish
scale(x: 20, y: -10) // 0.99-ish
```

Comment: Why are there downvotes on this? It appears to be exactly correct.

Comment: This is my first question in over a year... I forgot how hostile this place is. Wow. But, appreciate the support and the thoughtful answer @RobNapier!